# 40000 records in sdf - Performance

Tags: performance, search, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, import

I'm using sqlce 3.5 in Datalogic memor.

1. **Importing 40,000 records** to a table from other sdf inside this
   scanner, it takes for **3 minutes**.
2. **Searching a field** in this table, it takes **4 seconds**.

Is it a normal time? Could we speed up?

In this table, there are 6 fields below

1. nvarchar 30
2. nvarchar 26
3. nvarchar 40
4. nvarchar 13
5. datetime
6. nvarchar 20

System searchs field 2 and then load field 2, 3 and 4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the import you can use SqlCeUpdateableRecord and SqlCEResultSet (or use my SqlCeBulkCopy api, that wraps this).

For the select, make usre you have a Index defined, or consider using TableDirect and Seek.

Comment: thank you. I set unique index and primary key on the searching field 2. It really speeds up. Just take a second.